# glob_wildcards on multiple directories with different file names

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to write a rule that takes two files from different directories and the put the output of the rule into the same directory as in the file structure below:

```
DIR_A 
    dir1    
        file1.clean.vcf  
    dir2  
        file2.clean.vcf  
    dir3
        file1.output.vcf
        file2.output.vcf
```

so far I have tried using glob_wildcards:

```
(DIR,NAME) = glob_wildcards("DIR_A/{dir}/{name}.clean.vcf") 
input: expand("DIR_A/{dir}/{name}.clean.vcf", dir=DIR, name=NAME)
output: "DIR_A/dir3/{name}.output.vcf
```

but it throws an error:

```
MissingInputException in line 80 of DIR_A:
Missing input files for rule convert_output:

DIR_A/dir1/file2.clean.vcf
DIR_A/dir2/file1.clean.vcf
```

adding zip to input:

```
input: expand("DIR_A/{dir}/{name}.clean.vcf", zip, dir=DIR, name=NAME)
```

if $ snakemake -s snakefile -n (dry run):

```
rule conv_output:
input: DIR_A/dir1/file1.clean.vcf, DIR_A/file2/file2.clean.vcf
```

This is accepted by snakemake and prevents the above error, but now both file1.clean.vcf and file2.clean.vcf are both inputs to the rule but the {name} wild card makes the rule run once per file.  This ends up as a many files to one file rather than the one to one that I am looking for.

Is there a way to set this up so I can get the output of the rule conv_output to act on each of the files then put the output in dir3?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: May be you could write a python function to return a list of all input files, put them into a dictionary and then use it in a snakemake rule? Remember since Snakemake allows use of python code, you can think outside snakemake rule implementation, when needed.

Comment: @ JeeYem: Thank you for our comment! I am new to python and snakemake, could you elaborate on what that python function would look like and how to implement it within snakemake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using python, pair input vcf sample/filename to its path, and then use it to specify input path in snakemake rule. Below example works for directory structure given in the question.

```
from pathlib import Path   

def pair_name_to_infiles():
    # get all *.clean.vcf files recursively under DIR_A
    vcf_path = Path('DIR_A').glob('**/*.clean.vcf')

    # pair vcf name to infile path using a dictionary
    vcf_infiles_dict = {}
    for f in vcf_path:
        vcf_name = f.name.replace('.clean.vcf', '')
        vcf_infiles_dict[vcf_name] = str(f)

    return vcf_infiles_dict


# using function written in python code, map vcf name to their infile path
vcf_infiles_dict = pair_name_to_infiles()


rule all:
    input:
        expand('DIR_A/dir3/{vcf_name}.output.vcf', vcf_name=vcf_infiles_dict.keys())


rule foo:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: vcf_infiles_dict[wildcards.vcf_name]
    output:
        'DIR_A/dir3/{vcf_name}.output.vcf'
    shell:
        'touch {output}'
```